# Linkify не работает с JSOUP? Кликабельные ссылки

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Есть код для парсинга:

```
public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {

            Document doc;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(contentUrl).get();
                imagesRec = doc.select("div.post-featured-img amp-img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]");
                imgSrcUrl = imagesRec.attr("abs:src");

                doc.select("div.kc__wrap").remove();
                doc.select("div.kk-star-ratings").remove();
                doc.select("div.ampforwp-comment-wrapper > .h3").remove();
                Elements content = doc.select("div.the_content");
                Elements comments = doc.select("div.ampforwp-comment-wrapper");

                contentFinal = content.html();
                contentComments = comments.html();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            ImageView cntImg = findViewById(R.id.cntImg);
            Picasso.get().load(imgSrcUrl).into(cntImg);
            TextView cntContent = findViewById(R.id.cntContent);
            cntContent.setText(Html.fromHtml(contentFinal));
            Linkify.addLinks(cntContent, Linkify.ALL);
            TextView cntComments = findViewById(R.id.cntComments);
            cntComments.setText(Html.fromHtml(contentComments));
        };
```

Почему код

```
Linkify.addLinks(cntContent, Linkify.ALL);
```

Не работает? То есть, если есть эта строчка, то все ссылки со спарсенной страницы просто исчезают. Если же код убрать, то ссылки появляются, но с ними невозможно взаимодействовать.

**Возможно ли заставить ссылки стать кликабельными?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уберите `Linkify` - он убивает существующие ссылки и потом делает кликабельными
 url-адреса (которых уже нет).
Добавьте:

```
cntContent.setLinksClickable(true);
cntContent.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

И если в разметке у этого `TextView` есть атрибут `android:autoLink="..."` -  тоже уберите.

Comment: Спасибо, работает!